# Leer un segmento de un Stream en C#

Tags: c#

estoy programando un método que tiene como objetivo leer una parte de un `Stream` y escribirla en otro (el método escribe los datos desencriptados en otro `Stream`), el problema es que dicha lectura continua hasta el final de la secuencia (ya que este puede tener un tamaño superior al se desea leer), y necesito que se detenga en una posición específica. Este es mi código:

```
public void Decrypt(Stream input, Stream output, byte[] key, long bytesToRead)
{
    byte[] salt = new byte[32];
    input.Read(salt, 0, salt.Length);

    var _key = new Rfc2898DeriveBytes(key, salt, MAX_KEY_DERIVATIONS);  // MAX_KEY_DERIVATIONS = 1000
    var aes = AesEncryptionTool.GetRijndaelManaged(_key.GetBytes(salt.Length));

    using (var cs = new CryptoStream(input, aes.CreateDecryptor(), CryptoStreamMode.Read, leaveOpen: true)) {
        byte[] buffer = new byte[BUFFER_SIZE];  // BUFFER_SIZE = 1024 * 1024
        int read;

        while ((read = cs.Read(buffer, 0, buffer.Length)) > 0) {
            output.Write(buffer, 0, read);
        }
    }
}
```

Brevemente, `input` es el `Stream` que se debe leer hasta `bytesToRead`, y `output` es donde se escriben los datos leídos en `input`.
Necesito que la variable `bytesToRead` determina el punto de parada de la lectura. He descartado hacer una única lectura (con `cs.Read()`) debido a que el tamaño de los datos puede ser muy grande y por eso utilizo un buffer. 
Gracias.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Muy buenas, 
Puedes hacerlo de varias formas pero creo que lo mas claro seria ir acumulando el número de elementos que te quedan por leer y actualizarlo en cada iteración.

Por ejemplo:

```
public void Decrypt(Stream input, Stream output, byte[] key, long bytesToRead)
    {
        byte[] salt = new byte[32];
        input.Read(salt, 0, salt.Length);

        var _key = new Rfc2898DeriveBytes(key, salt, MAX_KEY_DERIVATIONS);  // MAX_KEY_DERIVATIONS = 1000
        var aes = AesEncryptionTool.GetRijndaelManaged(_key.GetBytes(salt.Length));
        var numBytesToEnd = bytesToRead; /*En la variable numBytesToEnd vamos actualizando el numero de bytes que nos quedan por leer
                                           que al iniciar son todos*/
        using (var cs = new CryptoStream(input, aes.CreateDecryptor(), CryptoStreamMode.Read, leaveOpen: true))
        {
            do
            {
                byte[] buffer;
                if (BUFFER_SIZE < numBytesToEnd)
                {
                    //Comprobamos siempre si el número de bytes que nos quedan no sea menor que el tamaño del buffer establecido
                    buffer = new byte[BUFFER_SIZE]; // BUFFER_SIZE = 1024 * 1024

                }
                else //si nos quedan por leer menos bytes que el buffer_size
                {
                    buffer = new byte[numBytesToEnd];
                }
                int read = cs.Read(buffer, 0, buffer.Length);
                output.Write(buffer, 0, read);
                numBytesToEnd -= buffer.Length;//Restamos los bytes que ya hemos leido

            } while (numBytesToEnd > 0); //Iteramos hasta que leamos todos los bytes deseados

        }
    }
```

Espero que pueda ayudarte.